# nested lists to make data frame using folder names

Tags: nested-lists

I am working with a folder that contains two layers of subfolders and the lowest level folder contains files in pdf and doc formats. I want to create a data frame where the names of the highest order folder are one column, and so on, where the text in the files is a value in the data frame. So I'd like to create something like:

States (layer 1 file names) Counties (Layer 2 file names, nested in each state name) Text

| States | Counties | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | A. | text1 |
| One | A. | text2 |
| One | B. | text1 |

I've set the wd to the folder with all of the state names and created an object
```states <- list.dirs()````

but not sure how to nest the second layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `pathlib`.
The `Path` object has a `parts` attribute.

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts)